# Problema con acceso a Servicio Web REST

Tags: java, webservice, rest, java-ee, restful

Tengo un web service rest en java, en el cual, ya he restringido el acceso a este, ya que genera un JSON con datos de los usuarios, el problema es que no se como hacer para que yo como admin si pueda acceder desde el navegador, por lo que he podido averiguar, necesito crear un "Authorization Header" pero no se como.

```
package com.gmail.brunodiazmartin5.rs.ws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64;


public class SecuredFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY = "Authorization";
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX = "Basic";
private static final String SECURED_URL_PREFIX = "secured";

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    if(requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath().contains(SECURED_URL_PREFIX)) {
        List<String> authHeader = requestContext.getHeaders().get(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_KEY);

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.size() > 0){
            String authToken = authHeader.get(0);
            authToken = authToken.replaceFirst(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX, "");
            String decodeString = Base64.decodeAsString(authToken);

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(decodeString, ":");
            String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

            if ("admin".equals(username) && "admin".equals(password)) {
                return;
            }

            Response unauthorizedStatus = Response
                    .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .encoding("No puedes acceder a recurso solicitado")
                    .build();

            requestContext.abortWith(unauthorizedStatus);

        }
    }
}

}
```

Clase de ejemplo que tengo para comprobar

```
package com.gmail.brunodiazmartin5.rs.ws;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("secured")
public class SecuredService {

@GET
@Path("message")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String securedMethod(){
    return "Esta API necesita login";
}
}
```

A esta última clase no puedo acceder, ya que me devuelve un mensaje de que debo estar logeado, que es lo que quiero, pero no se como hacer el login.

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres acceder desde el navegador? Puedes usar una herramienta más especializada, como Postman o Insomnia

Comment: Simplemente para saber luego, como hacer para poder acceder desde un cliente.

Comment: En chrome instala `Boomerang Client API soap rest` y me dices cuanto te cobran.